# Not able to set BorderRadius at bottomRIght side for Container

Tags: flutter, dart, border, flutter-container

I want to give bottom right corner radius to Container. For that I have set right and bottom border of the Container.

However, it is not allowing me to set the bottom right corder radius.

The following is the code.

```
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
            ),
            border: Border(
              right: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 1),
              bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 1),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            blockName,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        )
```

When I ran above code on console I was getting following error.

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Container                                      transfer_content_screen.dart:537
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: just remove border radius OR checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812778/a-borderradius-can-only-be-given-for-uniform-borders

Comment: I need to set the boarder and radius at bottom right side.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, try this

```
 Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        width: 90,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 1, bottom: 1),
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child:  Text(
                    "blockName",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Though I need to do some modifications but this answer was very close to what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(
              right: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "blockName",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: the bottom right border is cutting off. The border should also be shown. It should not be cut off.